Prove that $L_{2n}=L_{n}^2-(-1)^n2$ for $n=1,2,3,...$ via induction, where $L_{n}$ is the $n$th Lucas number.
Prove that  $L_{2n}=L_{n}^2-(-1)^n2$ for $n=1,2,3,...$ via induction, where $L_{n}$ is the  $n$th Lucas number.
For n=1 it's trivial
Checking for $n+1$:
I started with
$L_{2n+2}=3L_{2n}-L_{2(n-1)}$.
Now after applying the formula and rewriting terms, I ended up with expression below
$3L_{n+1}^2-6L_{n-1}L_{n+1}+2L_{n-1}^2-8(-1)^{n}$
So now if only we could show that the $L_{n+1}^2-3L_{n-1}L_{n+1}+L_{n-1}^2-5(-1)^{n}$ part is equal to $0$.
I tried using property $L_{n}^2=L_{n+1}L_{n-1}+5(-1)^{n}$ yet I got nowhere.
I’ve tried to address it from a few angles, and yet I could not come to the conclusion.

Do you have to use induction? It seems like the closed formula for Lucas numbers would make it very easy.

Yes, sadly, I do have to use induction for this.

Then make that a conditi9n in the question. A person shouldn't need to read the comments to know the whole question

I suppose you could prove the closed formula by induction and take it from there

Here is my induction.
Suppose the equation holds for $n = 1\ to\ k$ (strong induction);
We want to prove it holds for $n = k+1$, namely,
$L_{2k+2}= L_{k+1}^2 - (-1)^{k+1}2$
$=L_{k+2}L_{k}+ 5(-1)^{k+1}- (-1)^{k+1}2$
$=(L_{k+1}+L_{k})L_{k}+ 5(-1)^{k+1}- (-1)^{k+1}2$
$=(2L_{k}+L_{k-1})L_{k}+ 5(-1)^{k+1}- (-1)^{k+1}2$
$=2L_{k}^2+L_{k}L_{k-1}+ 5(-1)^{k+1}- (-1)^{k+1}2$
$=2L_{k}^2+L_{k}L_{k-1}+(-1)^{k+1}3$
Then by def. $L_{2k+2}= L_{2k+1}+L_{2k}$
$=(L_{2k}+L_{2k-1})+L_{2k}$
$=2L_{2k}+L_{2k-1}$
$=2L_{2k}+L_{2k-2}+L_{2k-3}$
$=2L_{2k}+L_{2k-2}+L_{2k-4}+ ... + L_{2}+L_1$
$=2L_{2k}+\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}L_{2i}+L_{1}$
$=2L_{2k}+\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}\left(L_{i}^2-(-1)^i2\right)+L_{1}$ (by induction)
$=2L_{2k}+\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}L_{i}^2-2\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}(-1)^i+L_{1}$
$=2L_{2k}+\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}L_{i}^2-L_0^2-2\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}(-1)^i+L_{1}$
$=2L_{2k}+L_{k-1}L_{k}-L_0^2-2\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}(-1)^i+L_{1}$ (use $\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}L_{i}^2 =L_{k-1}L_{k} $ )
Plug in $L_0, L_1$ and by the oddity of $k$
$=2L_{2k}+L_{k-1}L_{k}+(-1)^{k}$
$=2\left(L_{k}^2-(-1)^k2\right)+L_{k-1}L_{k}+(-1)^{k}$
$=2L_{k}^2+L_{k}L_{k-1}+(-1)^{k+1}3$
So it holds for $n=k+1$.

We'll proceed via strong induction, assuming that the appropriate number of base cases have been established.
You don't really need anything beyond the fact that a Lucas number is the sum of the previous two Lucas numbers, as well as two facts, both of which seem as though they would arise naturally from my starting point, and both of which are simple to show via induction:
-- First, $L_k L_{k+1} = 2 + \sum_{j =1}^k L_j^2$; I'll refer to this fact with (a).
-- Second, $\sum_{j=1}^k L_{2j} = L_{2k+1} - 1$; this'll be (b).
So.  Assume that the claim holds for all $ n \le k $ -- referred to as (h) below.  If we start by writing
$$L_{k+1}^2 = (L_{k-1}+L_k)^2 = L_{k-1}^2 + 2L_{k-1}L_k +L_k^2, $$
and continue working on this expression, then the proof follows in a more or less straightforward way.

 \begin{align} L_{k+1}^2 &= L_{k-1}^2 + 2L_{k-1}L_k +L_k^2 \\ &\overset{\text{(a)}}{=} L_{k-1}^2  + L_k^2 + 2 \left(2 + \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} L_j^2 \right) \\ &\overset{\text{(h)}}{=} \left(L_{2(k-1)} + 2(-1)^{k-1}\right) + \left(L_{2k} + 2(-1)^k\right) + 4 + 2\sum_{j=1}^{k-1} \left( L_{2j} + 2(-1)^j \right) \\ &\overset{(*)}{=} L_{2k-2} + L_{2k} + 2\sum_{j=1}^{k-1} L_{2j} + 4 + 4 \sum_{j=1}^{k-1}(-1)^j  \\ &\overset{ \text{(b)}}{=} L_{2k-2} + L_{2k} + 2\left[ L_{2(k-1)+1}-1\right] + 4 + 4 \sum_{j=1}^{k-1}(-1)^j  \\ &= \left[ (L_{2k-2} + L_{2k-1}) + (L_{2k-1} + L_{2k}) \right] + 2 + 4 \sum_{j=1}^{k-1}(-1)^j \\ &= L_{2k} + L_{2k+1} + 2 + 4 \sum_{j=1}^{k-1}(-1)^j \\ &= L_{2(k+1)} + 2 + 4 \sum_{j=1}^{k-1}(-1)^j. \end{align}

At $(*)$, note that $2(-1)^{k-1} + 2(-1)^k = 0$.
And so $L_{k+1}^2 - 2(-1)^{k+1} = L_{2(k+1)} + f(k)$, where
$$f(k) = 2  + 4 \sum_{j=1}^{k-1}(-1)^j - 2(-1)^{k+1}. $$
It remains to be shown that $f(k) = 0$ for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.
